# Like button - truncated url .. special case

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like

I found some hints here but neither are good for me. So the problem is, clicking on a Like button the popping window has the right generated link, but on the facebook page, I have only the base url.

OG tags: I cant set og tags because there are hundreds like buttons on the page at the same time.

I also used encodeURIComponents() for the url.

Interestingly, earlier it was working, we observed this problem at the end of 2012, so something FB changed. Code wasn't changed meantime.

Any idea how to get correct urls in the posts?

You can try it out yourself: 
madarmegfigyeles.hu - click on a bird icon then like (check the full url generated first, and then the post made by fb)

thank you

EDIT: if I hard code an url into the og:url tag, I get a "Circular redirect" error, with a 302 response code.

Comment: If you want to keep receiving help start to accept the answers.

Comment: Pardon me, I dont enable answers? How is it possible?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I revised my questions and accepted answers I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

> So the problem is, clicking on a Like button the popping window has the right generated link, but on the facebook page, I have only the base url.

Of course, because all your individual articles(?) redirect to your base URL, [as the debug tool clearly shows](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://madarmegfigyeles.hu/megfigyeles/65) – and so Facebook takes the latter as the intrinsic URL to like.

If you need this redirect in your app logic when a normal user visits the page – then you have to exempt Facebook’s scraper from it (f.e. via its user agent -> search)

Comment: Yes, I know it, I have to find why I get 302 error in debugger even if I hardcode an url into the og:url part. Have no clue..